# Javascript - How to use variable when writing table

Tags: javascript, html-table

I'm trying to print the value of a variable in the first column of my table, but when I run the method, I get the name of the variable instead

I have the following code

```js
function writeTable() {
  var table;
  var uInput = document.test.input.value;
  table = "<table><tr><th colspan=3>Table Header</th></tr>";
  table += "<tr><th>Column1</th><th>column2</th><th>column3</th></tr>";
  table += '<tr><td>uInput</td><td>Value2</td><td>value3</td></tr>';
  document.write(table);
}
```

```html
<form name="test">
  <input type="text" name="input">
</form>
<input type="submit" name="submit" value="Write Table" onclick="writeTable()">
```

Comment: String concatenation.

Comment: Also avoid the legacy DOM notation, `document.test.input.value;`. Modernize with something like `var uInput = document.querySelector('input[name="input"]');`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to change this line:

```
table += '<tr><td>uInput</td><td>Value2</td><td>value3</td></tr>';
```

To use [template literal](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals):

```
table += `<tr><td>${uInput}</td><td>Value2</td><td>value3</td></tr>`;
```

Or standard concatenation

```
table += '<tr><td>' + uInput + '</td><td>Value2</td><td>value3</td></tr>';
```

Comment: Standard concat, that's what I was looking for. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You need to concatenate the string:

```
table+= '<tr><td>'+uInput+'</td><td>Value2</td><td>value3</td></tr>';
```

Remember that everything between single or double quotes is interpreted as a string. However your `uInput` is a variable. To make sure JavaScript get's the variable you need to concatenate. That means pasting the string parts and the variable together using the `+`. Purgatory's answer has a nice ecmascript 6 solution too.

Answer (score 0):

use

```
table+= '<tr><td>' + uInput + '</td><td>Value2</td><td>value3</td></tr>';
```

to concatenate your string.As well as for the standards ,use

```
uInput = document.getElementsByName('input').value
```

in your javascript

Comment: There is no `getElementByName`

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/getElementsByName

Comment: You made my point. It's `getElementsByName`, not `getElementByName `

Comment: And using getElement**s**ByName() would return a collection so you would also have to iterate through them which you don't explain or give an example of making your answer not very useful / incomplete.

Answer (score 0):

In print statement, you have to concatenate variable with "+" sign. 
 Your function 2nd last row looks like:

```
table+= '<tr><td>'+ uInput + '</td><td>Value2</td><td>value3</td></tr>';
```

Comment: Yes, four other people already stated this. What does your answer add that theirs doesn't?